# Gzipped soap request in Jmeter

Tags: soap, request, jmeter, gzip

Is it possible to send a gzipped soap request?

I added an HTTP Header Manager with the following headers:

```
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=Utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

I added a Beanshell PreProcessor as a child of the request which needs to be encoded, and I defined the following script:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

// This only works for the HTTP Request, not Soap Request.
// String bodyString = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue();
String bodyString = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getXmlData();

byte [] requestBody = bodyString.getBytes();

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(requestBody.length);
GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(out);
gzip.write(requestBody);
gzip.close();

// This only works for the HTTP Request, not Soap Request.
// sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).setValue(out.toString(0));
ctx.getCurrentSampler().setXmlData(???);
```

My problem is the last line, how can I set xmlData?

Jmeter version 3.1

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace [SOAP/XML-RPC Sampler which is deprecated](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60727) with the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler
2. Upgrade to [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5) (or whatever is the latest version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)
3. Switch from [Beanshell to Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
4. Use `sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).setValue(out.toString(0));` in order to generate the request body.

Comment: Thanks so much Dmitri, but I can not change the jmeter version. Is it not possible to send a gzipped soap request with jmeter vs 3.1?